# Is it possible to create DynamoDB stream ARN without date of creation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If to enable stream in table setting,Latest Stream ARN looks like:

> arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/stream/2022-06-08T12:23:37.791

Is possible to create DynamoDB Stream ARN without date of creation and reference table by this ARN ?

> arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/stream

Comment: No. As its setup by AWS, not you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, as an Stream ARN has always the following syntax:

```
arn:${Partition}:dynamodb:${Region}:${Account}:table/${TableName}/stream/${StreamLabel}
```

and according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Stream.html), the StreamLabel is:

> A timestamp, in ISO 8601 format, for this stream.

However you can implement an initialization code to retrieve the ARN. For instance using the [list-streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodbstreams/list-streams.html) API call.

Using list-streams you can retrieve streams belonging to a specific table:

```
aws dynamodbstreams list-streams --table-name <TableName>
```

Answer (score 0):

With DynamoDB streams the ARN always appends ISO8601 timestamp.

You didn't clearly state the reason you did not want the timestamp, but a possible workaround could be to use Kinesis Data Streams with DynamoDB where the ARN does not have a timestamp appended.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/kds.html

Comment: Take into account that Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB has some important differences compared to DynamoDB Streams, for instance DynamoDB ensure no duplicated records, while Kinesis do not guarantee that duplicated records may occasionally appear in the stream.

Comment: Yes, they are not like for like. Full details on the differences can be found here if you're interested: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html